# Подключение пк с линукс debian к другим пк

Tags: linux, debian

В наличии присутствует лишний пк, и несколько человек, имеющих желание пользоваться  линукс дебиан на своих пк, но не имеющие возможности установить виртуальную машину, или вторую ос. Каким образом можно подключить мой пк с линуксом к удалённому компьютеру через интернет соединение?

Comment: ssh - стандартный на сегодняшний день механизм "подключения" к юникс-компьютеру.

Comment: Нужен гуй или достаточно терминала?

Comment: @Drakonoved сейчас работает без вайна

Comment: а если нужен «рабочий стол», то есть `vnc` и `rdp`...